# Exegesis of Numbers 28 ( specifically Numbers 28:8 ) lamb offered at twilight and the grain offering and the drink offering

Tags: law, numbers, sacrifice

> Numbers 28 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> Laws for Offerings
>
> 1 Then the Lord spoke to Moses, saying, 2 “Command the sons of Israel
>   and say to them, ‘You shall [a]be careful to present My offering, My
>   food for My offerings by fire, of a soothing aroma to Me, at their
>   appointed time.’ 3 You shall say to them, ‘This is the offering by
>   fire which you shall offer to the Lord: two male lambs one year old
>   without defect as a continual burnt offering every day. 4 You shall
>   offer the one lamb in the morning and the other lamb you shall offer
>   [b]at twilight; 5 also a tenth of an ephah of fine flour for a grain
>   offering, mixed with a fourth of a hin of beaten oil. 6 It is a
>   continual burnt offering which was ordained in Mount Sinai as a
>   soothing aroma, an offering by fire to the Lord. 7 Then the drink
>   offering with it shall be a fourth of a hin for each lamb, in the holy
>   place you shall pour out a drink offering of strong drink to the Lord.
>   **8 The other lamb you shall offer [c]at twilight; as the grain offering of the morning and as its drink offering, you shall offer it,
>   an offering by fire, a soothing aroma to the Lord.**

In Numbers 28:8,

1) Why does the aforementioned verse associate the lamb offered at twilight to the grain offering that occurred in the morning?

2) Also, could someone please clarify as to the purpose of mentioning the drink offering?

> other lamb you shall offer [c]at twilight; as the grain offering of
>   the morning and **as its drink offering**

Comment: Regarding question 2, the purpose of the drink offering - Are you asking in general what is a drink offering and what is the purpose of drink offerings, or are you asking specifically why a drink offering needs to be part of the permanent daily morning and evening offerings?

Comment: @jacob-m Thx for responses.  LOL, I have more questions that spawns out of this Q & A so I'll post them as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, read the text carefully:

> The other lamb you shall offer in the evening; as the morning grain offering and its drink offering, you shall offer it as an offering made by fire, a sweet aroma to the LORD.

The text points us to the offering up of the lamb as the primary subject matter. It then illustrates the manner in which the lamb was to be offered. It does this by referencing the way in which the morning grain offering and the drink offering were offered up. They were offered by fire unto the Lord. Therefore the lamb was to be offered by fire just as those offerings were.

If I were to rephrase this in my own words to draw out the meaning:

> You shall offer the other lamb in the evening in the same manner that you offered the morning grain offering and the drink offering that went with it: by fire, as a sweet aroma to the Lord.

Comment: Thx for responding. However, wouldn't it have been just as easy to phrase it by saying offer the other lamb in the evening just as you offered the morning lamb as a burnt offering in the morning? Why risk confusion by comparing/referring to grain offering in the morning? The bible's wording/phrasing risks causing confusion.

Comment: I personally don't find the phrasing confusing. I think it is well written. There certainly are many ways to phrase the same information, though, so for that reason I recommend using a tool such as BlueLetterBible.org to compare various translations of any particular text when you are having difficulty understanding in one. For instance, here is the side by side of various versions for this specific verse:

https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/num/28/8/t_bibles_145008